Cultivation with higher injection distance
In Gidney's paper on "magic state cultivation" he examines injection with distances of $d_1 = 3$ and $d_1 = 5$. As shown in both Figure 1 and Figure 2, there is a marked improvement between these distances, with $d_1 = 5$ achieving an error rate of $10^{-9}$, which is within a few orders of magnitude of the threshold needed for practical applications.
I was curious whether increasing this distance further could lead to even better fidelity, reaching the region I marked with a green circle in the Figure below. Are there any challenges in doing so? If so, would this be sufficient for practical applications?
Additionally, as shown in Figure 16, the error rate in those regions can be dominated by the escape and memory rounds, so assume that $d_2$ also increase to reduce the error rate in these rounds.


At least the way I describe it in the paper, the entire process before the escape stage is postselected. So its cost increases exponentially with the number of gates performed. The number of gates used to cultivate up to a fault distance of $d$ grows like $O(d^3)$, so the expected volume scales like $V = 2^{O(p d^3)}$. The CNOT scaling, on the other hand, is $V = O(d^3)$. Clearly they will separate; the cost of cultivation has a bomb in it. The practical question is how far you can push $d$ before the explosion; what's the constant factor hiding in $2^{O(p d^3)}$.
Considering the $d=5$ cultivation had around a $10^{-2}$ success rate at a noise strength of $10^{-3}$, and that $7^3/5^3 \approx 2.7$, I'd estimate that $d=7$ would succeed with probability $10^{-2 \cdot 3.7} \approx 4 \cdot 10^{-6}$. Where you drew the green circle is more like a success rate of $10^{-3}$. So... move that green circle three orders of magnitude to the right. Substantially worse than cultivating at $d=5$, then distilling.
On the other hand, at a noise strength of $10^{-3}/2$ the success rate of $d=5$ cultivation was $10^{-1}$ suggesting a success rate for $d=7$ of $10^{-2.7} \approx 2 \cdot 10^{-3}$. That's more in line with what you draw (but involved assuming better noise). Assuming even harder, at a noise strength of $10^{-4}$ the $d=7$ cultivation would probably succeed more than 10% of the time. That's totally viable, and I would guess gives output error rates below $10^{-20}$. This is one of the reasons the infidelity of cultivation is so sensitive to physical noise: not only does it get $O(p^d)$ scaling instead of $O(p^{d/2})$ due to using error detection, but a lower $p$ allows you to increase $d$ because a lower $p$ delays the cost explosion.

Thank you Craig!
